# Questions about spinlock mutex implementation via std::atomic_flag

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, spinlock

I'm currently reading a book called C++ concurrency in action. There is an example of spinlock mutex impl:

```
class spinlock_mutex
{
 std::atomic_flag flag;
public:
 spinlock_mutex():
 flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT)
 {}
 void lock()
 {
   while(flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
 }
 void unlock()
 {
   flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
 }
};
```

The first problem I faced in this sample is that operator= is deleted for std::atomic_flag and it doesn't compile. But if I remove ctor, and just make this instruction in private class section, everything is fine, no errors:
`std::atomic_flag flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT`
Why does it compile? Isn't it the same operator= used here?

The 2nd one thing I would like to ask is, how actually does looping process goes?

If I create:

```
spinlock_mutex mtx;
mtx.lock();

//some code

mtx.unlock();
```

And try to print some debug inside method's lock while-loop:

```
void lock()
{
  while (flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
    std::cout << "here" << "\n";
  }
}
```

it doesn't print anything, so it looks like it doesn't get inside, how do we achive looping then?

I've described 2 problems and what I've tried above.

Comment: How many threads contend for the mutex in your test? If the mutex is uncontested, then `flag.test_and_set(...)` will return `false` on the first try, and the `lock` function will execute _zero_ iterations of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

1. It sounds like you're mistaking `operator=` for [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).
   [`std::atomic_flag::operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/operator%3D) is deleted indeed, but `std::atomic_flag flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` does not use the assignment operator.
   It uses the [constructor of the flag](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/atomic_flag).
2. It's not going to print anything if the mutex is initially unlocked, i.e. if `flag` is unset.
   You need some contention, i.e. you need two separate threads that try to lock the mutex at the same time.
   If it doesn't enter the `while` loop, that means that it locked successfully without any waiting.